# Python Append replacing all elements in list

Tags: python, json, mongodb

I am confused as to why I can print data and it prints out unique entries but when I go to append previous data in the list is overwritten with the current data record.

```
data = {}
vegetablePlantList = []

while True:
    results = soup.find("table", {"id": "tablestyle"})
    #print(results)

    for result in soup.find_all('tr')[1:]:
        tableRows = result.find_all('td')
        #print ("Year: %s, Location: %s, Reactor: %s, Model: %s, GrossMWe: %s"  % \
        #   (tableRows[0].text, tableRows[1].text, tableRows[2].text, tableRows[3].text, tableRows[4].text))
        try:
            int(tableRows[0].text)
            data["Year"] = tableRows[0].text
            data["Location"] = tableRows[1].text
            data["Type"] = tableRows[2].text
            data["Model"] = tableRows[3].text
            data["Kilojoules"] = tableRows[4].text
            #print(data)
        except:
            pass

        vegetablePlantList.append(data)
```

Comment: It is because the `data` variable is a reference. In other words, the reference to the `data` variable is added to the `vegetablePlantList` object.

Answer (score 0):

You only create a single `data` object, then change that single object each iteration, and add multiple references to that single object to `vegetablePlantList`. They "all" change because they're all actually the same object.

To fix it, create the dictionary inside the loop so a new one is created on every iteration, instead of one dictionary being shared across all iterations:

```
for result in soup.find_all('tr')[1:]:
    data = {}
```